Understanding context for asynchronous services in ROS 2
Due to my last work, I have been working just with ROS for a while, and haven't paid much attention to ROS 2 meanwhile (I'm starting to regret it already). Now that I have more time, I wanted to go full on ROS 2 Jazzy, and while following ros 2 tutorials documentation (shoutout for the great effort done there), I was checking services when the future concept approached.
I'm writing this issue just to make sure I have understood everything correctly and share it with anyone who might encounter the same doubt, or if I need to be corrected :)
My first thought was the definition of service, as a synchronous task where a client node asks a server node for any specific data, and the client needs the response in order to keep working.
In C++ example, it uses the method async_send_request and checking the library (link here) there are no other methods which represent a synchronous call.
auto result = client->async_send_request(request);
  // Wait for the result.
  if (rclcpp::spin_until_future_complete(node, result) ==
    rclcpp::FutureReturnCode::SUCCESS)
  {
     // do some stuff
  }

So I suppose that there is no way of keeping the scope in the request. Also, would this solution work using OOP and be safe as well?
In Python example, since the newest version of the API is TBD (not filled yet), I use the API from version rclpy 0.6.1 (link here). Also there is a specific topic in the tutorials explaining this concept (link here)
    future = minimal_client.send_request(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))
    rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(minimal_client, future)
    response = future.result()

So, are synchronous calls still discouraged to be used? I'm still thinking how would aproach this using ROS but for obvious reasons, I suppose these changes were made to improve the performance and omit deadlocks.
Thanks in advance

Hi, I overlooked your question and did not realize that you got to the same link explaining the matter! Sorry!
In the quoted explanation Sync VS Async, they explain the risks of deadlocks using Sync calls and that's the reason why Async is prefered. Does this answer your question? Do you need a Sync behavior different from just waiting for the Async response?

Hey, sorry for the long time response. No worries. It actually does, I just wanted to make sure that this simple solution would work in most use cases, because I saw some people in the past that were having issues when porting their ROS code to ROS 2 due to this. Actually didn't understand why, that was the reason of my question. Thanks for clarification.

The previously mentioned link about Sync VS Async service clients  may be helpful.
From this link, it reads:

Async calls in rclpy are entirely safe and the recommended method of calling services. They can be made from anywhere without running the risk of blocking other ROS and non-ROS processes, unlike sync calls.


It is not recommended to implement a synchronous service client. They are susceptible to deadlock, but will not provide any indication of issue when deadlock occurs.

